# Mathematics of the "Wolf, Goat and Cabbage Riddle"

Tags: graph-theory, optimization

I have heard of a famous problem called the "Wolf, Goat, and Cabbage Riddle"  - supposedly this problem has existed since medieval times:(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wolf,_goat_and_cabbage_problem):

[image]

*"Once upon a time a farmer went to a market and purchased a wolf, a goat, and a cabbage. On his way home, the farmer came to the bank of a river and rented a boat. But crossing the river by boat, the farmer could carry only himself and a single one of his purchases: the wolf, the goat, or the cabbage. If left unattended together, the wolf would eat the goat, or the goat would eat the cabbage. The farmer's challenge was to carry himself and his purchases to the far bank of the river, leaving each purchase intact. How did he do it?"*

I have informally heard that this riddle can be seen as an optimization problem as it can be interpreted as a discrete optimization problem with integer constraints (i.e. certain combinations of items can not be left together). I have also heard that this riddle can appear in real life when there are thousands of objects and thousands of constraints (but I am not sure about this):

[image]

**Can anyone recommend some references in which the "Wolf, Goat and Cabbage Riddle" is studied as a mathematical problem involving Discrete Optimization and Graph Theory - or any references in which problems in the real world have come up that loosely resemble the "Wolf, Goat, Cabbage Riddle" for many objects and many constraints?**

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can check out this video on YouTube
https://youtu.be/ZCVAGb1ee8A

You can also check this article:
[The Alcuin Number of a Graph and Its Connections to the Vertex Cover Number](https://www.jstor.org/stable/41642576?seq=1)

You can also examine "[The Ferry Cover Problem](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-540-72914-3_20)" as a real life problem.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).